# Another beloved Add-A-Gram puzzle!

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

Well it's been a few days, so I figure, why not? Are you ready to solve another Add-A-Gram chain? Each word can form the next word by adding a letter and then forming an anagram. For example, **an insect** *in* **a beverage** *in* **red wood** would be **bee -> beer -> ember**.

Here is today's Add-A-Gram chain definition:

**a natural base** *in* **a grapheme** *in* **a division** *in* **a chieftain** *in* **imbibe** *in* **an extension** *in* **a Plymouth** *in* **a piece of pie** *in* **a metamorphic rock** *in* **a precept** *in* **surpassing** *in* **pertaining to two related systems** *in* **prophylactic repeating** *in* **neutralizing**.

As always, happy Add-A-Gramming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is:

> **e** — a natural base
>  **ae** — a grapheme, the ligature æ
>  **era** — a division (of time)
>  **earl** — a chieftain
>  **learn** — imbibe (or absorb)
>  **antler** — an extension
>  **reliant** — a Plymouth (car model)
>  **triangle** — a piece of pie, kind of
>  **granulite** — a metamorphic rock
>  **regulation** — a precept
>  **outlearning** — surpassing
>  **congruential** — pertaining to two related systems
>  **countersignal** — prophylactic repeating (in radio communicationq)
>  **countersealing** — neutralizing

Note: I'm not quite sure about the meaning of the last word.

Comment: Got stuck after the Plymouth part.. Well done!

Comment: I only had 11 of these when you posted... I missed the car model and didn't realize "prophylactic" was related to telecommunication.

Comment: The car models were my foot in the door here from which I worked up and down. I somehow suspected that it was about the car brand and tried the models with seven letters, which I got from the Wikipedia page. (It had to be seven letters, because the first one clearly was e.)

Comment: Well done! I wasn't sure if anyone would get the last two. Then again, this is Puzzling SE, and this is where geniuses live :)